# Performance of Apache-karaf container while deploying the bundle

Tags: java, osgi, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle

I creating a osgi bundle and using Apache-karaf as a osgi container. I am testing an application by putting logs and placing it in deploy folder to deploying the application. Everything works fine. while doing the testing the bundle id increases and after some iteration while deploying the application activate method is called two times.  I've verified the same in new apache-karaf it works as expected that activate method is called only once.
Note: The bundle is application with some simple print statements.

```
1. Is this performance issue in Apache-karaf container for reaching more number of bundle ids or kind of caching problem in apache-karaf.
2. Is this problem with deploying the bundle in deploy folder instead of osgi:install?
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with the deploy folder. It is monitored by felix fileinstall. So the schedule when it checks the file system will determine how it reacts.

Using bundle:install is much more reliable and also works great for testing. Simple deploy your bundle to you local maven repo by using maven install. Then install it into karaf using the mvn:groupId/rtifactId/version url.

If you then change your bundle you can simply upload it using maven install again and do update . This will reload from your local maven repo.

If you use a maven -SNAPSHOT version (which you should) then you can also use bundle:watch *. Karaf will then look for changes in the local maven repo and automatically update the bundles.

Comment: Could you please mention which version of deploy will have this issues so that i can take it appropriate version? or it is applicable to all versions of karaf?

Comment: I would advise to generally avoid the deploy folder.